# How to convert char * to uint64_t

Tags: c++, char, hex

I am beginner in c++. I have a char array offset. I need to convert char array to uint64_t. In fact, need to remove the brackets and write it to hex_offset.

```
char * offset = {"0xC45AC8"};
uint64_t hex_offset = (uint64_t) offset;
```

Comment: I recommend renaming `hex_offset` to just `offset`, to avoid confusion.  "hex" describes a way to __display__ a number, and your `uint64_t` doesn't know or care how you are imagining its value to be displayed.  It's just a number.

Comment: use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy (don't worry it will actually result in optimized assembly)

Comment: It seems you got off on the wrong foot with C++ at the first line: `char * offset = {"0xC45AC8"};` is not a valid C++ initialization. `"0xC45AC8"` is a character literal and those `char`s are `const` since you are not allowed change them.  Didn't the compiler have anything to say about that?

Comment: _"character literal"_ should be _string literal_ above

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a C-style null-terminated string with a number in hexadecimal representation to an integer of the data type `unsigned long long`, you can use the function [`std::stoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul).

You can then cast the value of type `unsigned long long` to the type `uint64_t`, because an `unsigned long long` is guaranteed by the standard to be large enough to represent all possible values of a `uint64_t`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    const char *input = "0xC45AC8";
    char *endptr;
    unsigned long long result1;
    uint64_t result2;

    //attempt to convert string input to an integer
    result1 = std::strtoull( input, &endptr, 16 );
    if ( endptr == input )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to convert input!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //verify that the result is representable in
    //the type uint64_t
    if ( result1 > std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() )
    {
        std::cout << "Value is out of range of a uint64_t!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //convert the result to the desired type
    result2 = static_cast<uint64_t>(result1);

    //print the result
    std::cout <<
        "Input successfully converted to uint64_t!\n"
        "The result is: " << std::hex << result2;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Input successfully converted to uint64_t!
The result is: c45ac8
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
char * offset = {"0xC45AC8"};             // invalid, should be `const char*`
uint64_t hex_offset = (uint64_t) offset;  // fine, but probably not what you want.
```

`hex_offset` will with the above be carrying the value representation of the address of the first character in the string literal `"0xC45AC8"` - which is very unlikely the value you want.

You need to interpret the string literal somehow. [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) was a nice addition in C++17. It's meant to be fast and doesn't throw exceptions so error handling has to be added by you. I'm showing where you could do error handling below by just throwing exceptions manually though.

I'd go for this interface:

```cpp
template <class T>
T convert_hex_string_to(const char* first); // implementation comes later

int main() {
    const char* offset = {"0xC45AC8"};

    auto hex_offset = convert_hex_string_to<std::uint64_t>(offset);

    std::cout << std::hex << hex_offset << '\n';
}
```

By making `convert_hex_string_to` into a function template, it can be used to convert any C string into the type of our choice. The usage,

```
auto hex_offset = convert_hex_string_to<std::uint64_t>(offset);
```

says that we'd like to convert the C string `offset` into a `std::uint64_t`.

The first implementation of that function template would be an overload that just calculates where the end of the C string is and passes it forward to another overload:

```cpp
template <class T>
T convert_hex_string_to(const char* first) {
    return convert_hex_string_to<T>(first, first + std::strlen(first));
}
```

The overload doing the heavy lifting could look like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
T convert_hex_string_to(const char* first, const char* last) {
    T result;

    if (std::distance(first, last) <= 2)  // we need at least 2 chars for "0x"
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            std::string(first, last) +
            " is a few characters short of a full hex string");

    // ... and they must be "0x" or "0X"
    if (*first != '0' ||
        std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(first[1])) != 'x')
        throw std::invalid_argument(std::string(first, last) +
                                    " is not a hex valid hex string");

    // ok, enough checking, lets try to convert:
    auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(first + 2, last, result, 16);

    if (ec == std::errc{}) {  // no error - now just check if the whole string
                              // was used in the conversion:
        // ptr should be equal to last if the whole string was consumed during
        // conversion:
        if (ptr != last)
            throw std::runtime_error("garbage in input: " +
                                     std::string(ptr, last));
    } else {
        // an error occured, let's throw something friendly if we can:
        switch (ec) {
            case std::errc::result_out_of_range:
                throw std::out_of_range(
                    std::string(first, last) +
                    " has a value out of range for the target type");
            case std::errc::invalid_argument:
                throw std::invalid_argument(std::string(first, last) +
                                            " is not a hex valid hex string");
            default:
                throw std::invalid_argument(
                    std::string(first, last) +
                    " is wrong in ways I don't know how to describe");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9q17rn8zv)